# no state update in the method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my state is not updated.console.log (newQuestion) - shows me e.g. 3 elements, and in qBank there are still 10 elements

```
gameIp= (id) => {
    const newQuestion2 = [];
    for (const point of this.state.qBank) {
        if (id === point.RouteId) {
            newQuestion2.push({
                question: point.Question1,
                answers: [...point.Answers],
                correct: point.Correct,
                id: point.Id,
            });

        }
    }
    this.setState({ qBank: newQuestion2 });
}
```

Comment: Need some more context. Please post a question with clarity according to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is `async` behaviour so if you run below code in sequence:

```
this.setState({ qBank: newQuestion2 });

console.log(this.state.qBank); // Will not show you updated state
```

---

If you want to check updated state, you can use `setState callback`

```
this.setState({ qBank: newQuestion2 } , () => {
    console.log(this.state.qBank); // <--- Here you can check updated state
});
```

---

> Due to this you might be confused that your state is not being update,
>   but the changes will be reflected in UI as soon as state is updated as
>   it will force dom to re render.